# Host WebApi and C# site under the same domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have a website made in C# (`http://my.site/`), and now i have a Web API project that i want to merge to that domain and listen on `http://my.site/api`. They are 2 separate projects in VS2013.

I tried uploading Web API to `/api/` subfolder in the server and map a MVC route to it (WebApi route in *WebApiConfig.cs* still `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`), expecting the default (Home) MVC controller to respond in `/api/`. The MVC route (in WebAPI's MVC routing):

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}", //Also api/{controller}
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But i get "Server Error 404" when accessing `http://my.site/api/` / `http://my.site/api/home` etc. I don't understand the nature of this error (most likely settings in the C# website in root folder), but one would think IIS would serve the default app inside the `/api/` folder.

So i want to know if adding `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` to `Global.asax` (*Application_Start()*) and adding *WebApiConfig.cs* to *App_Start* folder of the **C#** project (and using the respective namespaces) will solve the issue. This seem too simple to be true so i doubt it will work, so i need someone to point me in the correct direction, or i will commit the sin of going back to *asmx*.

If not, how can i have C# website and a WebAPI on same domain?

Comment: Are you expecting WebSiteA to be able to listen to and respond to request made for WebSiteB?

Comment: I have a WebForms (C#) website and i want to add the WebAPI i created to it.

Comment: Why not put your logic in a shared dll and add the web api libraries to your existing web forms project and create web api controller instances there as needed that call through to the library. That way you can still re-deploy it as a stand alone solution if you ever needed to but you can host your controllers directly in the same project. We currently do this as we wanted web api controllers in one of our legacy projects, no problems at all.

Answer (score 4):

You are wanting to run two separate dlls (each with their own routing rules) within the same bin folder on your server. That could definitely cause some conflicts in routing on your site. A proper way to do this would be to host your api project on a separate server and use a sub-domain, such as `http://api.my.site/`. That way you ensure that your C# site (`http://my.site/`)would have access to the api (`http://api.my.site/`). And your dlls, including routing rules, would remain separate.

Comment: This seems a reasonable suggestion, but rules out the possibility of having `my.site/api/` url, which seems to be the standard nowadays.

Comment: Typically, you use something like `my.site/api` if you have everything in one solution. Something like `api.my.site` is typically used when you have two separate solutions. And `api.my.site` is not uncommon at all.

Comment: I do realize it's a SEO-friendly solution and i will use your suggestion if it's impossible/messy to run the two projects on the same server folder (one in root other in `/api`)

Comment: This is a good suggestions. But I think my API routes won't conflict with my Web files, so, the question is that is it still good to go this way? Would there be some other conflicts apart from just the routes ?